# Is there a way to get the Progress of Web Audio Api decodeAudioData?

Tags: web-audio-api

I load Audio Files from the user, they can be MP3 or WAV files. Initially I just showed an spinner but (specially with WAV files) the user sometimes had the feeling the application crashed because "nothing" was happening.

The two big process here are the file reading and the `decodeAudioData` process.

For the first one I use a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)'s `onprogress` method but I can not find a similar option for the WebApi's `decodeAudioData`.

Is there a way to get the progress of `decodeAudioData`? I only found [this github feature request from 2014](https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/335#issuecomment-102286766) but nothing more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not exist for now. We've in the process of re-designing those APIs (and also the encoding side), and the new design will have a way to know the progress.

Comment: Where can I see the status of this?

Comment: https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/335 is the issue in our issue tracker. It's tagged "Todo V2", which means we're planning to have a look soon-ish.